# React Testing Lib: Best practice on querying translated strings?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am having a discussion with my team about what is the best practice when it comes to querying translated texts.

As those texts can be modified by non-developers (translators) we don't want our tests to be broken on each translation change. But a part of my teammates thinks we should keep on using plain strings, so our tests resemble user behavior...
In our current code we are doing something like this to find a button:

```
const buttonCHF = await screen.findByText('My button textl');
```

We are currently using react-intl, so I proposed a solution that would go like this to find the same button:

```
const buttonText = getNodeText(<FormatteMessage id="buttonText" />);
const buttonCHF = await screen.findByText(buttonText);
```

I think this would make the test more resilient, without breaking the rule of making tests the most similar as possible to user behavior, after all, we would be querying the same text as the user while avoiding unmaintainable strings. What do you think?

Comment: Could you have a no-op "translation" that just outputs the input string, then test against that? That way you're constantly testing the IDs that are used to look up the real translations, so you find out if they accidentally change.

Answer (score 3):

On my team we use react-i18next, and we mock the translation function (named `t`) like so :

```
// mock intl module
// in tests always return the translation key itself
jest.mock('i18n', () => ({
  addResourceBundle: jest.fn(),
  loadNamespaces: jest.fn(),
  t: (key) => key,
  language: 'en',
}));

// mock the hook (used like so in components :
// const { t } = useTranslation(namespaces);
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  useTranslation: () => ({ t: (key) => key, i18n: { language: 'en', changeLanguage: jest.fn() } }),
}));
```

You should be able to do something equivalent with react-intl.

This code is placed in setupTests.js at the root of the projecvt, since we use create-react-app (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#srcsetuptestsjs), but if you don't you still should be able to setup a test "pre run file" where you can mock things globally.

In our tests we check that the translation key is correct by using getByText function, so even if the actual displayed text changes, our test still passes.

For instance

```
<Button>{t('translationKey')}</Button>
```

...will be rendered as

```
<button>translationKey</button>
```

...in our test, so

```
screen.getByText('translationKey')
```

...will find our button.

Comment: Do you need to separately mock `react-i18next`, rather than letting it use the mocked `i18n`? That seems quite awkward; if you refactored to switch to the HOC and got `t` from props instead, your tests would suddenly stop working.

Comment: Good point...I tried to add useTranslation in i18n mock, it works fine and seems much cleaner. I'll dig into this !

Comment: Could you please add an example jest file.